# What is Stablesats?

Tags: satoshi, stable-coin

What is Stable sats and how actually the entire process happens behind the scenes without fiat integration or without stablecoins?

Comment: Where did you read about such thing?

Comment: They have a prominent three minute video in their site, have you watched that one?

Comment: @Mercedes Yes I did, but how can we short Lightning Channel's BTC. We can't take that BTC out of channel and then Hedge that BTC right?

Comment: I don't know LN in depth, but I think funds in channel are locked for payments once opened until closed. If you want to earn interest on tokens, it might be wiser to find some other token with uncapped emission maybe?